# What's the error of my .sql that I cannot import it to workbench?

Tags: mysql, database

[image]

```
`-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump `
`-- version 4.1.14`
`-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net`
`--`
`-- Host: 127.0.0.1`
`-- Generation Time: Jan 19, 2015 at 07:14 AM`
`-- Server version: 5.6.17`
`-- PHP Version: 5.5.12 `

`SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";`
`SET time_zone = "+00:00";`

`/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;`
`/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;`
`/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;`
`/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;`
`/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;`
`/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;`
`/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;`
`/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;`
`/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;`
`/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;`

`--
-- Database: `artsclassdb`
--`


`--
-- Table structure for table `subject`
--`



`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `subject`;`
`/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;`
`/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;`
`CREATE TABLE `subject` (
  `subid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subtitle` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `subtime` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subday` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subroom` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
`/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;`
`--
-- Dumping data for table `subject`
--`

`LOCK TABLES `subject` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `subject` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `subject` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES; `

`--
-- Table structure for table `subjecttask`
--`


`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `subjecttask`;
`/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;`
`/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;`
`CREATE TABLE `subjecttask` (
  `subtaskid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subtasksubject` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subtasktask` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subtaskid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
`/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;`
`--
-- Dumping data for table `subjecttask`
--`

`LOCK TABLES `subjecttask` WRITE;`
`/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `subjecttask` DISABLE KEYS */;`
`/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `subjecttask` ENABLE KEYS */;`
`UNLOCK TABLES;`

`--
-- Table structure for table `task`
--`

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `task`;
`/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;`
`/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;`
`CREATE TABLE `task` (
  `taskid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tasktitle` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `taskdescription` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `taskstatus` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `taskdate` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`taskid`))` `ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
`/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;`

`--
-- Dumping data for table `task`
--`

`LOCK TABLES `task` WRITE;`
`/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `task` DISABLE KEYS */;`
`/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `task` ENABLE KEYS */;`
`UNLOCK TABLES;`

`--
-- Dumping events for database `artsclassdb``
--`
`/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;`

`/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;`
`/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;`
`/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;`
`/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;`
`/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;`
`/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;`
`/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */; `

`-- Dump completed on 2015-02-02  1:20:30`
```

Comment: In the future, please copy error message as text instead of screenshots.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "no database selected" in the error.

Start the SQL file with `USE databasename;` and you should be fine. *databasename* being the name of your database that you want to import to.

If you're still using the name artclassdb, then it's:

```
USE artclassdb;
```

Answer (score 1):

add an

```
use artclassdb;
```

to the top of your code.